# How to capture image to Documents directory uses AVFoundation

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

friends
I use AVFoundation and Swift and capture photo. Below my code

```
func captureImage(completion: @escaping (UIImage?, Error?) -> Void) {
    guard let captureSession = captureSession, captureSession.isRunning     
else { completion(nil, CameraControllerError.captureSessionIsMissing); return }

    let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
    settings.flashMode = self.flashMode

    self.photoOutput?.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
    self.photoCaptureCompletionBlock = completion
}
```

How to capture image only to Documents app directory uses AVFoundation?
I think maybe capture to standard Camera Roll and then save image to Documents and delete from Camera Roll. But i Think is bad idea.

How to save only to Documents? 
Please help

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the new image capture flow yet, but I did some research in the docs.

Quoting the docs in AVCapturePhoto:

> When you capture photos with the AVCapturePhotoOutput class, your
>   delegate object receives each resulting image and related data in the
>   form of an AVCapturePhoto object. This object is an immutable wrapper
>   from which you can retrieve various results of the photo capture.

If you look at `AVCapturePhoto` in the Xcode docs, there is a method `fileDataRepresentation()` that will return image data ready for writing to a file (the data format is determined by the settings in the AVCapturePhotoSettings you create). You could simply save that data to your documents directory.

`AVCapturePhoto` also has a function `cgImageRepresentation()` that will give you a CGImage for the captured photo, which you can then process as desired.